# jquery ui, YUI or dojo or other framework that emulates browser tabs

Tags: jquery-ui, select, tabs, clone, dijit.layout

There are plenty of frameworks (jquery, dojo, yui, ext js, etc.) that offer tabs as a part of their extensive ui library.  But I have not yet found one that resembles the tabs you'd find in a browser that also includes a last 'tab' with a plus sign that allows you to add more tabs.

In my case, I wish to clone tabs, but the look would emulate the browser look.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

YUI is the closest I could come up with as far as widgets are concerned:
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/tabview/addtab.html

However, I am motivated to do something similar using dijit.layout.  May need to build this myself.